# Inverse of the sum of two orthogonal projections

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

I am trying to find out, if there is a formula for finding the inverse of the sum of two orthogonal projections. So basically my questions is:

If $\left[\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B}\right]$ is full rank, then
$\left(\mathbf{A}\left(\mathbf{A}^{\mathrm{H}}\mathbf{A}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{A}^{\mathrm{H}} + 
\mathbf{B}\left(\mathbf{B}^{\mathrm{H}}\mathbf{B}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{B}^{\mathrm{H}}\right)^{-1}$ = ?

Comment: What kind of answer are you expecting on the right hand side of the equation?

Comment: I was hoping, that there is closed-form expression for that. Something such that I can express the inverse analytically and used it in my further derivations.

Comment: Let me reformulate it: you are looking for $(P+Q)^{-1}$ whenever $P^H=P^2=P$ and $Q^H=Q^2=Q$. Are you supposing any more relation between the projections $P$ and $Q$ (e.g., are their images orthogonal to each other)?

Comment: yes, you are right, that is a better formulation. no, there are no other assumptions, if they were orthogonal complements the answer would be $\mathbf{I}$, but I was wondering if there is a formula in the case they are not.

Comment: I think you also want the assumption that $\mathrm{ker}(P) \cap \mathrm{ker}(Q) = 0$.

Comment: you are right, $\mathrm{ker}(\mathbf{P})∩\mathrm{ker}(\mathbf{Q}) = 0$ is necessary to make the inverse possible, in the original formulation it is covered by the full rank of $\left[\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B}\right]$.

Answer (score 1):

A projection splits your vector space (which I guess here is $\mathbb{R}^n$), and expresses it as a direct sum of the image and the kernel. Obviously, everything in the kernel is sent to $0$. On the image, the projection acts by the identity.

So now consider the sum of two projections, $P$ and $Q$. 
We can divide up the vector space as a direct sum of four subspaces: $\text{im}(P)\cap\text{im}(Q)$, $\text{im}(P)\cap\text{ker}(Q)$, $\text{ker}(P)\cap \text{im}(Q)$ and $\text{ker}(P)\cap\text{ker}(Q)$.
As we want to find the inverse, we're assuming that $P+Q$ has no kernel, so the last of these four is trivial, and we only have three parts to deal with.

On $\text{ker}(P)\cap \text{im}(Q)$ the map $P+Q$ acts as the identity. The same is true of $\text{im}(P)\cap\text{ker}(Q)$. So the inverse on those subspaces is the identity.

On $\text{im}(P)\cap\text{im}(Q)$ the map $P+Q$ acts as twice the identity, so the inverse there is half the identity.

All that's left then is to apply the change of basis needed to get between a basis that matches the direct sum to the one you are interested in.